# Why does this inline stopPropagation method call not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have this button:

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    onclick='parent.parent.ExecuteCommand(14);event.stopPropagation()' 
    class="button_air-medium">
    <img 
        id="selectMode" 
        class="shortcutContant" 
        src="../stdicons/icon_select.gif">
</button>
```

As you can see inside onclick attribute I call 2 functions `ExecuteCommand` and `stopPropagation`.

The execute command works fine but it seem to me that `stopPropagation` method is not fired because the element under the button is influenced.

Any idea  why stopPropagation method is not working?

Comment: I think `stopPropagation()` belongs to jQuery. Instead just use `return false;` it should do the trick

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself here is what is `event` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

There is likely no `event`available to the inline handler in the browser you are using

You will have an easier time if you do

```
$(function() { 
  $(".button_air-medium").on("click",function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    parent.parent.ExecuteCommand($(this).data("commandnumber")) 
    // or return false here
  });
});
```

using

```
<button type="button" data-commandnumber="14"
class="button_air-medium"><img id="selectMode" class="shortcutContant" 
src="../stdicons/icon_select.gif"></button>
```

If you want to stop the image from handling events you could try

```
$(function() { 
  $(".button_air-medium").on("click",function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    parent.parent.ExecuteCommand($(this).data("commandnumber")) 
    // or return false here
  });
  $(".button_air-medium > img").on("click",function(e) {
    $(this).parent().click();
    return false; 
  });
});
```

or find where it is handled and edit that handler

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Errors in the console? Nothing? Change it to return false  and it does work? With the code you gave I cannot tell

Comment: I added return false in place your comments, I don't get any errors in console.And the element under the button is influenced.

Comment: So a child of the button? Then you need to block the click on the image. that was not clear in your question - please try the updated version

Comment: Yes I have to block click on the underlayer element(I have button it has some z-index on the map).

Comment: thanks for post.But I think that stopPropagation() have to do the work why I need to use on() method?

Comment: Events only bubble UP - what do you mean by the second question? Why not "on"?